# Telerik's Rad Grid Edit Mode Switching

Tags: telerik, radgrid

Here is my requirement,

```
I want to use only Batch Edit mode in my Rad Grid for editing & pop up for inserting.
```

While inserting I want to switch it to pop-up because there are a lot of columns/fields in my grid.

I've tried looking in several tickets in the Telerik's portal, but I couldn't find exact answer. Here are some links which I've tried on.

**Note**: Rad Grid's Batch Edit mode heavily depends on client side. Only Java Script answers are preferable.

1. [Mixing Edit Modes](https://www.telerik.com/forums/mixing-batch-edit-mode-with-pop-up-or-edit-form)
2. [Switch Mode only from In-Place to Pop Up](https://www.telerik.com/forums/change-editmode-from-inplace-to-batch-client-side)

None of the above answers helped me.